# Java Inflater throws a DataFormatException "invalid code length set"

Tags: java, saml, inflate

I am using the inflater to decompress a SAMLRequest. Since this value is compressed with GZIP i managed to pass "true" to the inflater constructor, in order to provide compatibility with such format. However, the inflating line throws a DataFormatException.

```
    private String decodeMessage(String SAMLContent) {
        try {
            //URLDecode, Base64 and inflate data

            //URLDecode
            SAMLContent = URLDecoder.decode(SAMLContent, "UTF-8");

            //Base64 decoding
            byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(SAMLContent);
            SAMLContent = new String(decode, "UTF-8");
            //SAMLContent = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(SAMLContent), "UTF-8");

            //Inflating data
            try {
                byte[] inflated = new byte[(10 * SAMLContent.getBytes("UTF-8").length)];
                Inflater i = new Inflater(true);
                i.setInput(SAMLContent.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, SAMLContent.getBytes("UTF-8").length);

                //The following line throws DFException
                int finalSize = i.inflate(inflated);

                SAMLContent = new String(SAMLContent.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, finalSize, "UTF-8");
                i.end();

            } catch (DataFormatException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DFE: " + ex.getMessage());  //Returns "invalid code length set"
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "UEE: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return SAMLContent;
    }
```

The exception is raised at line 20. The workflow I'm trying to replicate is

1. Copying the value of the request ([This one for instance](https://shrib.com/#SportiveLemur2L0Mo2Q))
2. Use [this URL decoder to decode it](https://www.samltool.com/url.php) (the bottom-left textbox)
3. Paste the result of the second step in this [Base64decoder + inflater](https://www.samltool.com/decode.php) in order to get the original XML, as shown in the third textbox of the last page.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use [OpenSAML](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OS30/Home) or have a look at their [code](https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/sites/site/java-opensaml/3.4.2/apidocs/org/opensaml/saml/saml2/binding/decoding/impl/HTTPRedirectDeflateDecoder.html) and extract relevant parts.

Comment: Since it was a simple step and, for now, the only function I need, I wanted to write it without using external libraries. I am adding an answer with the working algorithm. However, I will surely keep in mind OpenSAML in case I need it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of the several conversions between byte array and string, which was probably causing an information loss somewhere. This is the working code I am using.

```
private String decodeHeader(String SAMLContent) {
    try {
        SAMLContent = URLDecoder.decode(SAMLContent, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "UEException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    byte[] deflatedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(SAMLContent);
    byte[] inflatedBytes = new byte[100*deflatedBytes.length];
    Inflater compressor = new Inflater(true);

    compressor.setInput(deflatedBytes, 0, deflatedBytes.length);

    try {
        int size = compressor.inflate(inflatedBytes);
    } catch (DataFormatException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DFException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        return new String(inflatedBytes, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "UEException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "This shouln't be printed");
    return null;
}
```